# How can I databind an image?

Tags: xamarin.forms

**How can I databind an image using XAML?**

Specifically, I have a stream object that I would like to convert into an image.

However, I just cannot find a basic example of how to do this.

**1. What does the viewmodel property look like?**

- Do I use an ImageSource?
- Do I need a value converter?

**2. What does the XAML look like?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms has a [StreamImageSource](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource/) you can use to do this.  However, I don't think you can use it in XAML without writing a custom converter.  To use it in code, you would do something like this:

```
image1.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
{
  // whatever you need to do to create your stream
  return stream;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The demo illustrates the binding via code.  For a `XAML` implementation you need something along the lines of:-

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyImageAsBytes, Converter={StaticResource MyByteToImageSourceConverter}}" />
```

Once you have your `byte[]` in your `ViewModel`, you **will** need a converter to convert this byte array, that contains the image, to a `Xamarin.Forms` `ImageSource`.

The converter, takes the `byte[]` array and converts to an `ImageSource` via:-

```
objImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytImageData));
```

**Example:-**

```
StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout();

byte[] bytImage = { your image as a byte collection }

this.BindingContext = new MyImageViewModel()
{
    MyImageAsBytes = bytImage
};

Image objImage = new Image();
objImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "MyImageAsBytes", converter: new MyByteToImageSourceConverter());

objStackLayout.Children.Add(objImage);
```

**ViewModel:-**

```
public class MyImageViewModel
    : Xamarin.Forms.View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MyImageAsBytesProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MyImageViewModel, byte[]>(p => p.MyImageAsBytes, default(byte[]));

    public byte[] MyImageAsBytes
    {
        get { return (byte[])GetValue(MyImageAsBytesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyImageAsBytesProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Converter:-**

```
public class MyByteToImageSourceConverter
    : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object pobjValue, Type pobjTargetType, object pobjParameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo pobjCulture)
    {
        ImageSource objImageSource;
        //
        if (pobjValue != null)
        {
            byte[] bytImageData = (byte[])pobjValue;
            //
            objImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytImageData));
        }
        else
        {
            objImageSource = null;
        }   
        //
        return objImageSource;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object pobjValue, Type pobjTargetType, object pobjParameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo pobjCulture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```