# Circular referenced IValueConverter in Application.Resources

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting the error :

```
StaticResource not found for key maxLength
```

the setup is as follows:

Converter setup in app.xaml, which also contains a datatemplate

```
          <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
              <ext:MaxLengthStringConverter x:Key="maxLength"/>
    ....
          <DataTemplate x:Key="HotelViewModel">
            <tripSegmentPartViews:HotelView
                    Padding="0"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    BorderWidth="1"
                    BorderColor="{ext:ColourResource Divider}"
                    BordersToDraw="{x:Static controls:Borders.Top}"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     ....
```

view in the HotelView.xaml which is in the datatemplate, uses the converter

```
....
      <Label Text="{Binding HotelName, Converter={StaticResource maxLength}, ConverterParameter=10}"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
              AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0.2,0.62,0.5"
              VerticalOptions="End"
              HorizontalOptions="Start"
              FontSize="20"
              />
....
```

If I move the converter to HotelView.xaml resource dictionary it works

If I change the reference to a DynamicResource it is not used

Obviously with something as basic as max length (which shortens the string and adds '...' if its over the required length) I want to be able to use it through out the application, and not have to reference it in multiple resource dictionaries.

Is this a bug?

----------------- edit ------------------

OK I have reproduced this errror with a minimum app consisting of:

App1.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.App"
             xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:App1.Extensions;assembly=App1"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1;assembly=App1">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ext:MyConverter x:Key="conv"></ext:MyConverter>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="dt">
        <local:View1></local:View1>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Page1.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Page1"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1;assembly=App1">
  <StackLayout>
  <Label Text="Page1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" />
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dt}" ItemsSource="List">

    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

View1.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.View1"
             xmlns:ext="App1.Extensions">
  <Label Text="{Binding MainText, Converter={StaticResource conv}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>
</ContentView>
```

App1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // The root page of your application
            Page1 p = new Page1();
            p.BindingContext = new {
                MainText = "test",
                List = new List<string>() { "test"}
            };
            var navContainer = new NavigationPage(p);
            navContainer.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Red;
            navContainer.BarTextColor = Color.White;

            MainPage = navContainer;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is thrown at runtime using the VS emulator

Answer (score 0):

From what you mention you want to be able to define a `IValueConverter` the once, and use it from any `Xamarin.Forms` `ContentPage`, without the need to keep specifying the converter in the local `XAML` page.

This can be achieved by doing the following:-

In your `PCL` you normally have `App.cs`.

You will need to delete this, and add a new `Forms Xaml Page` called `App.cs`.

This will generate both the `App.xaml` and related `App.cs` files.

In this question, ([How can I databind an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558260/how-can-i-databind-an-image/35561621#35561621)), there is a converter called `MyByteToImageSourceConverter`.

I will illustrate using this:-

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SampleApp.App"

         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:{namespace reference goes here to the converter}"
         >

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <local:MyByteToImageSourceConverter x:Key="kyByteToImageSourceConverter"/>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

So in the above we have defined our converter with a key, that we will then be able to reference from **all** other `Xamarin.Forms` `ContentPage`'s.

**App.cs**

```
namespace SampleApp
{
    public partial class App
        : Xamarin.Forms.Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            this.MainPage = new ByteToImageExample2();
        }
    }
}
```

In the `code-behind` we need to change the default inheritance from `ContentPage` and specify `Xamarin.Forms.Application`.

We also specify our launch page, via the `this.MainPage = ...`

**ByteToImageExample2.xaml**:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="SampleApp.ByteToImageExample2"
         >

    <StackLayout>

        <Image Source="{Binding MyImageAsBytes, Converter={StaticResource kyByteToImageSourceConverter}}"/>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

In our `ContentPage` we can see above we are referencing the converter that we specified in `App.xaml` via the `StaticResource kyByteToImageSourceConverter`.

As that was definied in `App.xaml`, we can re-use this in all our pages without the need to specify the location of the converter locally.

For completeness the code-behind is:-

**ByteToImageExample2.cs**:-

```
public partial class ByteToImageExample2 : ContentPage
{
    public ByteToImageExample2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        byte[] bytImage = { your image as a byte collection }
        //
        this.BindingContext = new MyImageViewModel()
        {
            MyImageAsBytes = bytImage
        };
    }
}
```

**Update 1:-**

You can have the following in your `App.xaml`:-

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="kyByteToImage3ExampleDataTemplate2">
    <ViewCell>
      <local2:MyCustomView1/>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
```

with `local2:MyCustomView1` referencing your custom view, which for this example is defined as:-

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SampleApp.MyCustomView1">

    <Image Source="{Binding MyImage, Converter={StaticResource kyByteToImageSourceConverter}}" Aspect="AspectFit" />

</ContentView>
```

This custom view still uses a `Converter` as specified from the `App.xaml` and does still render, **without** the need to specify the `Converter` locally within the `ContentView` class.

Comment: Thanks for your long reply pete, unfortunately this is what I already have setup. If you add a datatemplate to your app.xaml resource dictionary which references a view which uses the converter does it work for you?

Comment: @Ewan I've updated my answer (See **Update 1**) based on changes to your question.  If you define a `DataTemplate`, refererencing a custom `View`, you can still access your resources defined in App.xaml from the custom `View`.

Comment: I can't see where ive gone wrong then, it definatly works for you? Ill check my code and see if I can narrow it down

Comment: @Ewan Yes - the example above is actual code.  If you need any further assistance my contact details are on my profile.

Comment: well I've recreated this with minimal code, I'd be interested to see how yours differs

Comment: @Ewan, the above is the actual code, it should contain all the steps.  If you pop your version across on email I will compare and get back to you.  My contact details are on my profile.

Comment: thank ill send it across, your above code dosnt use the datatemplate it defines

Comment: @Ewan did you get resolution on this. I have a very similar issue?