# App StaticResource used in ContentView throws Exception

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a ContentView that uses a static resource in the App.xaml. The app resource is a custom DataTemplateSelector

```
<c:ControlTemplateSelector  x:Key="controlTemplateSelector"
                    PickerWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource pickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"
                    DatePickerWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource datePickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"    
                    TimePickerWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource timePickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"    
                    MultiPickerWorkflowItemTemplate ="{StaticResource multiPickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"                 
                    NumberPickerWorkflowItemTemplate ="{StaticResource numberPickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"
                    MultiPickerWithOptionWorkflowItemTemplate ="{StaticResource multiPickerWithOptionWorkflowItemTemplate}"
                    SwitchWorkflowItemTemplate ="{StaticResource switchWorkflowItemTemplate}"
                    GridWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource gridWorkflowItemTemplate}"                        
                    TextBoxWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource textBoxWorkflowItemTemplate}">

</c:ControlTemplateSelector>
```

As soon as I add

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="horizontalStackContainerWorkflowItem">
        <c:HorizontalStackContainerWorkflowItem />
</DataTemplate>
```

to the ResourceDictionary in App.xaml I get a runtime exception:

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Timeout exceeded gettingexception details

The consuming view:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
                 x:Class="Positron.Mobile.Controls.HorizontalStackContainerWorkflowItem"
                xmlns:vmc="clr-namespace:Positron.Mobile.ViewModel.Controls;assembly=Positron.Mobile"
                 x:Name="ContentView"
                xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Positron.Mobile.Controls;assembly=Positron.Mobile"
                 >

        <ContentView.Content>
            <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource controlTemplateSelector}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ControlViewModels}" >
    ...

            </ListView>

        </ContentView.Content>
    </ContentView>
```

**EDIT: 
This seems to be the actual exception that is thrown. I just don't know why I cannot use the Resource in my data template.**

> StaticResource not found for key controlTemplateSelector

It seems to be very similar to the following issue [Circular referenced IValueConverter in Application.Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654775/circular-referenced-ivalueconverter-in-application-resources)

**EDIT**
The below works but is obviously not that great since you would not want to define all your ContentViews in the App.xaml resource dictionary. So would still like someone to tell me how to accomplish it without this work around.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="horizontalStackContainerWorkflowItemTemplate">
                <ContentView>
                    <ContentView.Content>
                        <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource controlTemplateSelector}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ControlViewModels}" >
...

                        </ListView>
                    </ContentView.Content>
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
            <c:ControlTemplateSelector  x:Key="controlTemplateSelector"
                    PickerWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource pickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"
                    DatePickerWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource datePickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"    
                    TimePickerWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource timePickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"    
                    MultiPickerWorkflowItemTemplate ="{StaticResource multiPickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"                 
                    NumberPickerWorkflowItemTemplate ="{StaticResource numberPickerWorkflowItemTemplate}"
                    MultiPickerWithOptionWorkflowItemTemplate ="{StaticResource multiPickerWithOptionWorkflowItemTemplate}"
                    SwitchWorkflowItemTemplate ="{StaticResource switchWorkflowItemTemplate}"
                    GridWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource gridWorkflowItemTemplate}"                        
                    TextBoxWorkflowItemTemplate="{StaticResource textBoxWorkflowItemTemplate}"
                    HorizontalStackContainerWorkflowItemTemplate ="{StaticResource horizontalStackContainerWorkflowItemTemplate}">
            </c:ControlTemplateSelector>
```

Comment: Also can you share stacktrace from the logs?

Comment: Yes it is. I am new to xamarin, so excuse my ingnorance. But I just get the Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Timeout exceeded gettingexception message with zero stacktrace.

Comment: If some controls have the same namespace, but have been defined in two difference assemblies, then you will need two different prefix(es).

Comment: For stacktrace - would recommend looking into the application-output window

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>... but no stacktrace (output window)

Comment: If I add <DataTemplate x:Key="horizontalStackContainerWorkflowItem"> in App.xaml and change the ContentView to <ListView   ItemsSource="{Binding ControlViewModels}" > it also runs fine. So it seems to have a problem with using the ControlTemplateSelector when the DataTemplate exists at the same time. Note that I am using the ControlTemplateSelector in another ContentPage which works perfectly.

Comment: Finally got a better exception StaticResource not found for key controlTemplateSelector. I just don't get why not.