# Xamarin - How to display en Image from an Object property

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In xamarin I have a class where one of the property is an "IMAGE type". 
I got this image from one Cloud API I developed myself.
I want now to display this image through a ListView and ImageCell. I'm wondering if there is is a way to bind my "Image" from my object directly thanks to the "ImageSource".

The class is declared the following(indeed the image is created from Byte[]:

```
    public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public bool HasSize { get; set; }
    //public virtual List<SizedMeal> AvailableSizes { get; set; }
    public bool CanBeSalt { get; set; }
    public bool CanBeHotNotCold { get; set; }
    public bool CanHaveMeat { get; set; }
    public bool CanHaveSauce { get; set; }

    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

Where IMAGE is comming from using Xamarin.Forms

and the object is constructed the following way:

```
                Image image = new Image();
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(item.Image);
                image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return stream; });
                ImageSource imageSource = image.Source;
                resto.Menu.ItemList.Add(new Item
                {
                    Name = item.Name,
                    Brand = item.Brand,
                    Image = image,
                    UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice,
                    Description = item.Description,
                    HasSize = item.HasSize,
                    ItemId = item.ItemId,

                });
```

Thanks,

Comment: what exactly is IMAGE type?  How is it defined and initialized?

Comment: @Jason I updated the post. The I would like to use my resto.Menu.ItemList.Image directly to display the image....

Comment: Image is a UI control - it doesn't really make sense to store it in a domain object.  How are you actually getting the data (item.Image) in the first place?  If you just want to bind to a stream, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558260/how-can-i-databind-an-image

Comment: @Jason Indeed I collect this image from a server API. And I received in Json as part of the similar equivalent object in my Back end. Indeed I make this chose to work that way on the back end side, because those image are small and want to keep a consistent management of my object (to not split my object with a file to be stored (and maintained) on the server). On the back-end is quite simple to use, I have a render URL I call to display it on my web-page... 
So here do I have to store on a local file? Is there a way to make a render method that can be bind with the page?

Comment: if you have the images available via a url, just bind to that.  Or if you are returning the image as a byte array, then bind to that (see link in my last comment)

Comment: `var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(source);
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(()=>stream);
MyImage.Source = imageSource;`